# Database optimisation

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I'm starting a web application that will be used by a lot of companies (over 20K), and most importantly a lot of information will be recorded daily. I would like your advice on the following idea: create a database for each company to do sql queries like this:

```
select * from enterprisedb1.tablename;
select * from enterprisedb2.tablename2 where enterprisedb2.tablename2.col='foo'
```

Pleace i need your advice, i don't find anything on google

Comment: One database, a few tables, many clients.  Not many databases, not many tables.  All clients in one set of tables, unless you have a really good reason.

Comment: I imagined an application that manages more than 30,000 schools (students, evaluations, teachers, courses, accounting, time use for each school) after 5 years, the amount of data.

Comment: You are going to have so much fun mantaining it - and administrative tasks would be a nightmare! I would highly suggest against it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are selling this to multiple clients then it might come down to separation of their data.

On the one hand everything for the app is in the one database for each client, and provided you get the connection string right you probably don't need to ever specify the company name again for the rest of the app. No more "where customer=123" on every single query.

Also means a client could be deleted, backed up, moved, audited, whatever in a completely independent manner.

And also means there is no risk of a developer or a query accidentally doing cross-client things. So you can even open up to generic query access that still cant accidentally cross a client-to-client border. And security set-up will be simpler.

But if you have a million clients you do end up with a *lot* of databases. How well this works will depend on all sorts of things, including your database of choice.

You also end up having multiple copies of reference data unless you create an additional database "common" or something like that.

Its going to be very much a "depends" answer, but that's a few things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use common tables for each company. It will better to manage and easy to understand.
Create one table for company data and use Integer reference of that key in another mete data tables. For better performance, Index and Query must be well formed.